# Can MySQL dump be used for Cloud Bees

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

I'm new to MySQL and Cloud Bees so I wanted to know that can I use the mySQL database in my computer to link it with my web application on cloud bees via "mysqldump" tool??

Comment: Ask the Cloud Bees folk or see http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can upload your own mysql data to the cloud version of MySQL.